# Unzip a file and process its contents using AWK and pipes

Tags: awk, pipe, zip

I need to unzip a log file, and then display some specific columns of that log file using awk. Can it be done using pipe?

```
unzip log.zip | awk -F "- -" '{pring $1 " " $2} >newfile
```

Comment: does `log.zip` contain only one log file, or does it contain several?   if only one, then use gzip (or bzip2 or xz) to compress the file.   BTW, unix practice has always been to separate compression and archiving (e.g. compress or gzip or whatever for compression, tar or cpio or whatever for archiving).  ms-dos (and thus windows) practice is to do both compression and archiving at the same time).  unix practice is more convenient for working with compressed data in a pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `unzip`'s `-c` option to uncompress the .zip file's contents to stdout....otherwise it will uncompress the file(s) in the .zip file onto the disk, and there will be nothing to pipe into `awk`.

Like many programs that originated from MS-DOS/Windows instead of Unix, `unzip` also waffles on verbosely about what it's doing.  Unix programs generally don't do that until you explicitly tell them to with a `-v` or `--verbose` or `--debug` option or similar.  It's a significant cultural difference between dos/windows and unix software.  and programmers.

From the POV of any program taking input on stdin, that is almost certainly garbage that is going to confuse it (this is why unix programs aren't verbose unless you tell them to be).  So tell `unzip` to "just shut up and get to work" with the `-q` (quiet) or `-qq` (extra quiet) option.

e.g.

```
unzip -qq -c log.zip | awk -F'- -' '{print $1, $2}' >newfile
```

BTW, I've changed your `awk` script slightly.  I fixed the `pring` syntax error.  Also, the default output field separator (`OFS`) in `awk` is a single space...even if you set the input field separator (`FS`) to something else (e.g. with `-F'- -'`).   So I just printed `$1,$2` - no need to use a double-quoted space character.

Comment: Try `-p` instead of `-c`. From unzip's manual page: "This option (`-c`) is similar to the `-p` option except that the name of each file is printed as it is extracted". So if you're using `-c` make sure to consider the filename in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
awk -F "--" '{print $1 " "$2}' <(gzip -dc log.zip)
```

The gzip command uses the `-d` and `-c` options.

```
    -c --stdout --to-stdout
          Write output on standard output
    -d --decompress --uncompress
          Decompress.
```

You can of course use standard redirection to send the output to a file

```
awk -F "--" '{print $1 " "$2}' <(gzip -dc log.zip) > my_out_file
```

As Cas pointed out in the comments, gzip works for most .zip files but isn't guaranteed to work with all of them, you can use `unzip` with this command.

```
awk -F "--" '{print $1 " "$2}' <(unzip -cq log.zip) > my_out_file
```

The options are slightly different but the result is the same.

Comment: `gzip` isn't `zip`.   Info-zip's `unzip`  does have a `-c` option, though, to uncompress the contents of the .zip file to stdout.

Comment: gzip works for the `.zip` file here, i just tried the `-c` on the `unzip`, this also works, although it is slightly messy with the output you get.

Comment: gzip works for most .zip files but isn't guaranteed to work with all of them.  It really depends on the exact compression method used for the file(s) inside the .zip.    BTW, try the `-q` or `-qq` options with `unzip` to shut it up.  Or redirect stder from unzip to /dev/null

Comment: ah ha the -q did indeed shut it up. Thank you.

Comment: it's worse than i thought.  unzip prints stuff to stdout, not just stderr unless you shut it up with `-q`.