Replace string in file without temp file
I have a multi-gigabyte text file and I want to replace all occurrences of utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci in it with utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.
Usually, I’d use sed -i for this as suggested here: find and replace a string in a file without using temp file with SED
However, this creates a temp file under the hood and I need this replacement to occur in an environment that won’t have the disk space to support that.
How can I modify the file in-place?

Is the replacement string of the same length (in bytes) as the string to be replaced?

Nope, I've edited the question to clarify

An alternative would be to do the replacement as I unzip the file in the first place I suppose?

If you're extracting the file, yes, that would be easier. However, zip is annoying to use for it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425312/unzip-a-file-and-process-its-contents-using-awk-and-pipes Is it really a zip file, or a compressed tarball?

Files are basically just arrays of bytes which can be written over, but to insert or delete something in the middle, you need to rewrite everything after that to move it to the new position. There's no primitive operation in the OS level for adding or removing something in the middle. Meaning replacing something with an equal length string is pretty straightforward (if the tools support it), and replacing something with a shorter string is relatively simple since you can process the file in one go, reading to find the matches and writing everything in the new position.

But replacing with longer strings means you might write over the old data before you've read it, and to do the rewrite starting from the end you'd need to know how far to move the data in advance.

@muru - It's a single gzipped file, no tarring

@ilkkachu - Could you not calculate how far it needs to move by basically doing number of instances of found string * byte delta?

@ScottishTapWater, sure, you just can't do that in one pass. You'd need to read through the file once to count the matches and anyway the logic of moving the data part by part from the end is a bit more complex than just streaming it in order. A real database format or something would be way better suited for inserts and deletions...

If it is gzipped, please mention that in the question! Do you need to keep the file compressed or is decompressing it part of your pipeline? Can you just zcat file.gz | sed ... > uncompressed.file for example?

@terdon - I didn’t mention it in the question, because I’d already unzipped it before trying to modify it with sed

Do you want to have it uncompressed? There's almost never a good reason to keep text files in an uncompressed state. Would you have the space to do something like zcat file.gz | sed ... | gzip > fixed.file.gz && rm file.gz? Also have a look at How do I remove the first 300 million lines from a 700 GB txt file on a system with 1 TB disk space?.

@terdon - Yes, the file needs to be uncompressed at the end as it's being read my mysql from its init directory. Will take a look at you rlink

mysql can restore from a dump read on stdin, so you can use sed and pipe the output straight into mysql.

Exactly. Or you could tell it to read from <(zcat file) instead. There are various workarounds, but you cannot do in-place text replacement without a temp file somewhere.

Yeah, unfortunately, this is inside a docker build context, so the mysqld isn't actually running which makes it way more tricky. I'm dumping the export into docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and then patching the entrypoint script so iti initialises the db but doesn't then start up mysqld. I have actually worked around the issue now by just using a self-hosted runner but thanks for the help and mueh's answer looks good!

Just for fun, I tried an in-place replacement bash script, myreplace.
Obviously, do not use this without saving your original data first and
doing extensive testing. It
might have problems with files over 4G bytes, though as the numbers are
over 32 bits. Also, if there are millions of matches, tac is going to use
up memory or temporary file space.
I also had to hack up a small perl script to do a seek(2), but there must be one somewhere already.
#!/bin/bash
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/784361/119298
file=${1?}
str1=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
str2=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

len1=${#str1}
len2=${#str2}
let len3=len2-len1
if [ "$len3" -lt 0 ]
then echo "bad len $len3. dont need this script"; exit 1
fi
echo "2nd str bigger by $len3"

# grep -c counts lines so ignores 2 matches on a line, not what we want
nummatches=$(grep -a -o -b -F "$str1" "$file" | wc -l)
let need=nummatches*len3
echo "$nummatches matches, need $need bytes"
filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$file")
echo "filesize $filesize"
let src=filesize
let dest=filesize+need
let i=nummatches

# open 2 filedescriptors on same file, to read from and write at
exec {fdr}<"$file" {fdw}<>"$file"
seek <&$fdr $src; seek <&$fdw $dest # seek to both eofs

blocksize=10240 # arbitrary optimisation
# move overlapping from,to,numbytes
domove(){
    local from=${1?} to=${2?} numbytes=${3?} partlen
    while [ $numbytes -gt 0 ]
    do  if [ $numbytes -gt $blocksize ]
        then    partlen=$blocksize
        else    partlen=$numbytes
        fi
        seek <&$fdr -$partlen; seek <&$fdw -$partlen
        dd <&$fdr >&$fdw ibs=$partlen count=1 iflag=fullblock status=none
        seek <&$fdr -$partlen; seek <&$fdw -$partlen
        let numbytes=numbytes-partlen
    done
    seek <&$fdw -$len2
    printf "%s" "$str2" >&$fdw
    seek <&$fdw -$len2
    seek <&$fdr -$len1
}

grep -a -o -b -F "$str1" "$file" |
sed 's/:.*//' |
tac |
while read offset
do  echo "match $i at src $offset"
    let tomove="src-(offset+len1)"
    echo "move all from $offset+$len1 .. $src ($tomove bytes) to $dest-$tomove"
    echo "insert $len2 bytes of 2nd string to $dest-$tomove-$len2"
    echo "skip back over $len1 bytes of 1st string"
    domove $(($offset+$len1)) $(($dest-$tomove)) $tomove
    let src=$offset
    let dest=dest-tomove-len2
    let i=i-1
done


The principle is to use grep to find the byte offsets of the matches,
then use tac to reverse this list so we start at the end.
We open 2 file descriptors on the file. fdr will be our current reading
position, and fdw our write position. They both start at the end of the
file, but fdw is at the new notional end, which is further on by
nummatches times len3, the difference in length of the replacement string.
We use function domove to seek back on the reader by an amount, seek back
on the writer by the same amount, read and copy the amount to the writer.
We then need to seek back again to our new positions.
We seek back in the reader to skip over the old string. On the writer we
seek back, write the replacement string, and seek back over it.
I created a demo file to test with (str1 is from the script):
file=/tmp/myfile
man bash | sed 's/ brace / '"$str1"' /g' >"$file"
cp "$file" /tmp/orig
./myreplace "$file"
diff -u /tmp/orig "$file"

My perl is a bit rusty, but here's the perl script "seek":
#!/usr/bin/perl
# seek on stdin to given position
use strict;
use Fcntl 'SEEK_SET','SEEK_CUR';
sub usage{
    printf STDERR "usage: [+|-]9999  where sign means relative\n";
    exit 1;
}
my $offset = shift @ARGV;
my $flag = SEEK_SET;
my $sign = 1;
if($offset =~ s/^-//){$flag = SEEK_CUR; $sign = -1;}
elsif($offset =~ s/^\+//){$flag = SEEK_CUR;}
if($offset!~/^\d+$/){ usage(); }
usage() if(scalar @ARGV!=0);
$offset *= $sign;
if(!seek(STDIN,$offset,$flag)){
    printf STDERR "failed to seek to $offset: $!\n";
    exit 2;
}

